# VS 2005/2008 "Unrecognized configuration section startup" error while loading designer

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-ce

I have a really old C# Windows CE project. One day both Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 stopped opening its forms in designer with error:

> One or more errors encountered while loading the designer. The errors are listed below. Some errors can be fixed by rebuilding your project, while others may require code changes.
>
> Unrecognized configuration section startup. (D:\Soft\Visual Studio 2005\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config line 3)
>
> at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
>
> at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
>
> at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
>   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)

(from VS2005)

Project wasn't changed. I tried reinstalling VS with no effect. Maybe it's caused by a Windows update (I use Windows 10).
Any ideas how to solve the issue?

Comment: Do you have .NET Framework 3.5 installed?

Comment: @dai Of course. I even reinstalled it.